# Xamarin - Show text if CollectionView empty

Tags: xamarin, count, collectionview, items

I have a CollecitonView that gets populated in the OnAppearing method. 
This CollectionView is inside a StackLayout, and below the CollectionView I added a label with `x:name="hint"`

This code populates the CollecitonView

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        if (!App.galisloaded)
        {
            App.galisloaded = true;
            BindingContext = new GalleryListViewModel();

            (BindingContext as GalleryListViewModel).GetGalleriesCommand.Execute(null);

            ************HERE*************

        }        
    }
```

I would like in the marked spot to add a counter for the entries, so if there is at least 1 entry in my CollectionView then it should remove visibility from `hint`. But after 1 hour of trying I cannot figure out how to get the count of my entries.

Comment: to do it this way you would need to count whatever collection in your VM is the CollectionView's source.  Since you haven't shown that code I can't give you a specific example.  Or, you can use the `EmptyView` property as shown below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CollectionView` has a built in function to handle [empty views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/emptyview)

```
<CollectionView EmptyView="No items to display" ... />
```

Comment: Thank you very much! works great! Is there a way to add a new line? i tried \n but did not work..

Comment: you can display a custom view instead of simple text.  Read the linked docs

Comment: For example, a simple line break ( \n ) would be represented as &#x0a; , for \r\n you'd use &#x0d;&#x0a; and so on